# VB.net Price Calculation

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an application to display the total price of a order. It decides the price based on the number of items ordered and if the customer is a wholesale or retailer.

Calculation it uses:

1-4 items = $10 per item if wholesaler.

5+ items = $9 each if wholesaler.

1-3 items = $15 per item if retailer.

4-8 item = $14 per item if retailer.

9+ item = $12 per item if retailer.
I'm stuck on the calculation and confused as to how I would do it.

The GUI is complete, here is what I have so far:

Picture of GUI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nQIN.png

```
Dim quantity As Decimal
Dim price As Decimal
Dim wholesaler As Integer
Dim retailer As Integer

Integer.TryParse(txtUnits.Text, price)

chkRetailer.Text = retailer
chkWholesale.Text = wholesaler


If wholesaler Then
    If Quantity <= 4 Then
        Price = 10
    Else
        Price = 9
    End If
ElseIf retailer Then
    If Quantity <= 3 Then
        Price = 15
    ElseIf Quantity <= 8 Then
        Price = 14
    Else
        Price = 12
    End If
End If

lblTotPrice.Text = price * quantity

lblTotPrice.Text = price.ToString("C0")
```

It's the calculation I'm confused on, I have the display and the declarations correct I believe.

Thank you.

Comment: Your retailer/wholesaler controls should be RadioButtons, not checkboxes.

Comment: You've got a very basic data-flow problem here.  You should **not** set the chkRetailer.Text property from retailer.  You must set retailer from the chkRetailer.Checked property.  And retailer must be a variable of type Boolean.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your source file to help catch logical mistakes like that.

Comment: you don't really explain what you mean by stuck on the calculation. calculation appears to be price * quantity. I also recommend changing the checkboxes to radio buttons, because with checkboxes, you can select BOTH (the program would mark it as a wholesaler)

Comment: What issue are you having, this seems ok.  You're overwriting lblTotPrice.Text at then end with the wrong value though.  I'd also suggest using radio buttons versus checkboxes, since I assume you can't be both a retailer and a wholesaler?

Comment: It is displaying incorrectly.

Comment: This is the *fourth* time you asked this question and you haven't learned anything from the answers.  Please stop.

Comment: @HansPassant, I think "fourth" is being too kind.  Seems like it's been more than that.

Answer (score 2):

This would be much clearer using  [Case statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (The VB example of the link provided is very helpful)

First use an `IF` statement to determine if you are a wholesaler and that  determines which of the two case statements assigns the valid price

Comment: Your accusation is perplexing. Maybe specifying which calculation you are confused with would give you responses better suited to your needs.

Comment: Also the last line of your code overwrites the second to last line which is probably why you aren't seeing the results you want

Comment: This answer does not meet quality standards as it's not constructive.

Comment: haha... best of luck finding someone who will meet your definition of constructive!

Answer (score 0):

It'll be simpler if you nest your if loops as follows.  (I'm using pseudocode here.)

```
If Wholesaler Then
  If Quantity <= 4 Then
    Price = 10
  Else
    Price = 9
  EndIf
ElseIf Retailer Then
  If Quantity <= 3 Then
    Price = 15
  ElseIf Quantity <= 8 Then
    Price = 14
  Else
    Price = 12
  EndIf
End If

TotalCost = Price * Quantity
```

Comment: Updated OP, this answer helped a little, but still need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors here.

This statement is taking the input from the txtUnits and assigning it to price.

```
Integer.TryParse(txtUnits.Text, price)
```

These two lines are doing nothing but assigning 0 to the text property of the checkboxes.

```
chkRetailer.Text = retailer
chkWholesale.Text = wholesaler
```

These statements will always evaluate to False as they will always equal 0. Price will never be assigned.

```
If wholesaler Then
  'never reaches here
ElseIf retailer Then
  'or here
End If
```

You are making two assignments to the label. This one

```
lblTotPrice.Text = price * quantity
```

is useless because it is immediately being replaced by this

```
lblTotPrice.Text = price.ToString("C0")
```

Comment: I'm not going to just give you the answer. What happens when you step through the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it right, but then you assign to lblTotPrice the price * quantity, and then assign price.  Try this for the last two lines

```
Dim subTotal as integer
subtotal = price * quantity 
lblTotPrice.Text = subtotal.ToString("C0")
```

There are also some other things you could do that may help, such as using Select Case statements that will work a little bit better in the code, but I think this is your main problem.